# Creating custom post-listing templates in twentyseventeen child theme

Tags: templates, css, page-template, body-class

I'm using a child theme based on 'Twenty Seventeen' and have created a custom post type ('review').

I want to make two Pages, one which lists 'reviews' and the other which lists a mixture of 'posts' and 'reviews' (ordered by recency).

For the first of those I've made a copy of Twenty Seventeen's `index.php`, as `page-reviews.php`, and added code like this at the start:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'review',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Then, further down, replaced `have_posts()` and `the_post()` with `$the_query->have_posts()` and `$the_query->the_post()` respectively.

If I choose to use that template for a Page then it works in that the 'reviews' are listed, *but* the layout is all messed up. There are a lot of classes in the `<body>` which mess up the layout.

For example, the standard blog front page, using `index.php`, has these classes in its `<body>` and looks fine:

```
blog logged-in admin-bar hfeed has-header-image has-sidebar colors-light customize-support
```

While my custom page has these:

```
page-template page-template-page-postslist page-template-page-postslist-php page page-id-15071 logged-in admin-bar has-header-image page-two-column colors-light customize-support
```

How can I make a custom template that acts more like `index.php` in terms of the classes it adds?

Comment: I think you should check which classname is the one being used in CSS, then update the CSS to work with your template. a template `acting` as another template doesnt soung right, you can just use the original template.

Comment: Thanks, but that seems impractical - there are a lot of elements on the page that are rendered differently due to the differing classes. If there's a simpler way to make a Page list a Custom Post Type, or a mixture of Post Types, I'd be happy with that too!

Comment: For the reviews, you could give the custom post type an archive, and then customize archive.php. That might get the default styling closer to index.php's.

Comment: Ah, thanks WebElaine! This helped the solution click... I had to set the `has_archive` (and `rewrite`) settings when making my custom post type. Then WP automatically uses `archive.php` and I don't need that particular Page I'd made!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Body Class Filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/body_class) for this to adjust the classes being added to the `body` tag.

```
add_filter('body_class','review_pages_classes');
function review_pages_classes($classes) {
    $classes[] = 'blog';
    return $classes;
}
```

Which classes you need to add or remove is probably a matter of trial and error, or looking at the stylesheets in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I will create a shortcode which you can put on any page you want. Paste the following code to the **functions.php** file

```
add_shortcode('review-list', 'show_review_list');

function show_review_list($attr){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'review',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    ob_start();

    //...
    //Put code from index.php here to get the correct HTML structure
    //just like what you did before
    //

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

To use, put **[review-list]** anywhere on the page/post.